# Could not migrate and how to set mysql DB using Django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am beginner of `Django python`. When I am running into this `python manage.py migrate` I am getting the following error.

```
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Here also I am trying to create one crud application with `MYSQL` database which is present inside localhost means I need to connect to my localhost database .I need to also know how to connect it inside the `settings.py` file with all credentials. My `settings.py` file is given below.

**settings.py**:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#=0(1b4%2y!3(hs%_4v&_*(-j#c#8__s6^=1+b0eqrar7810h+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Please help me to resolve the above issue and connect to DB.

Comment: According to the comment in your settings.py you have download django 1.6 while this feature was available from django 1.7 onwards.

Comment: Perhaps `syncdb` can help...

Comment: Moreover, settings.py has nothing to do with Unknown command: see manage.py

Comment: @RajaSimon : Can you post your solution plz ?

Comment: Ditch this ancient version there is absolutely no reason to start a new project with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`migrate` command found in Django version 1.7 and above. You should use `syncdb` what it can do is create a database table and rows for you based on your models.

If you want more migrations like latest Django on Django 1.6 please consider use [south](https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I understood but how to use those inside code file because I am totaly new and trying to learn these languages.

Comment: You don't have to do major code changes in your codebase. Installation instruction will be found in here https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: And this is important https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation

Comment: And then here https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Comment: Please why not consider switching to latest Django ?

Comment: i used like this `python manage.py syncdb` and it created something.

Comment: yes it's created database file. You can see that file created in your project fodler like db.sqlite3 something ?

Comment: Yes true. Can you help me for my next problem actually I created one db in my mysql in localhost apache server and i need to connect there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146130/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-subhra).

Answer (score 0):

Default database: sqlite3

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Change to mysql:

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER' : 'username',
        'PASSWORD' : 'password',
        'HOST' : 'your ip',
        'PORT' : 'port',
    }
```

In django new version. I have to do 3 step to migrate

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py sqlmigrate svace <version of data>
python manage.py migrate
```

End of answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have data you want to migrate execute this command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

Next step: change database configuration to MySql:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'your-db-name',
        'USER': 'your-username',
        'PASSWORD': 'your-password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Then execute:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

To restore the data type:

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```